# Jboss EAP caching the user roles

Tags: jboss, openshift, wildfly, redhat, jboss7.x

I am using the Jboss EAP 7 version for deploying one of our application and it is integrated with SAML for authentication and authorization.

one of the user in this application has added with new role and when I try to print the role inside the application using SamlPrincipal class like below it is not showing the new role added.

```
Map<String, List<String>> attributeValues = samlPrincipal.getAttributes();
```

I would like to know, Will this Jboss server as default cache anything for the user - role mapping and how to disable this using standalone-openshift.xml?

Anyhelp on this is appreciated.

Thanks,
Harry